# RxJava2 Flowable that emits results of multiple network calls without using create?

Tags: kotlin, rx-java2

I have a generic screen that subscribes to an RxJava2 flowable that returns a List.  It then displays the content in the list.

I have a use case now though where I need to collect data from multiple endpoints, and emit data  once some complete, and then emit data again once the remaining ones complete.

I'm doing this using Flowable.create() but I've seen a lot of posts saying that there's usually a better and safer way to do so than using create? I seem to believe that is the case since I need to subscribe to an observable within the observable which ideally I wouldn't want to do?

Because I subscribe within, I know the emitter can become cancelled within the observable while other network calls are completing so I've added checks to ensure it doesn't throw an error after its disposed which do work (at least in testing...) *[I also just remembered I have the code available to dispose of the inner subscription if I kept it like this, when the outer is disposed]*

The first 2 calls may be incredibly fast (or instant) which is why i want to emit the first result right away, and then the following 4 network calls which rely on that data may take time to process.

It looks roughly like this right now...

```
return Flowable.create<List<Object>>({ activeEmitter ->
        Single.zip(
                single1(),
                single2(),
                BiFunction { single1Result: Object, single2result: Object ->

                    if (single1result.something || single2Result.somethingElse) {
                        activeEmitter.onNext(function(single1result, single2result) //returns list
                    }

                    Single.zip(
                            single3(single1result),
                            single4(single2result),
                            single5(single1result),
                            single6(single2result),
                            Function4 { single3Result: Object,
                                        single4Result: Object,
                                        single5Result: Object,
                                        single6Result: Object ->
                                ObjectHolder(single1Result, single2Result, single3Result, single4Result, single5Result, single6Result)
                            }
                    )
                }
        ).flatMap { objectHolder ->
            objects.flatMap { objectHolder ->
                Single.just(parseObjects(objectHolder))
            }
        }.subscribeBy(
                onError = { error ->
                    if (!activeEmitter.isCancelled) {
                        activeEmitter.onError(error)
                    }
                },
                onSuccess = { results ->
                    if (!activeEmitter.isCancelled) {
                        activeEmitter.onNext(results)
                        activeEmitter.onComplete()
                    }
                }
        )
    }, BackpressureStrategy.BUFFER)
```

I can't figure out another way to return a Flowable that emits the results of multiple different network calls without doing it like this?

Is there a different/better way I can't find?

---

I worked this out given ctranxuan response.  Posting so he can tweak/optimize and then I accept his answer

```
 return Single.zip(single1(), single2(),
            BiFunction { single1result: Object, single2result: Object ->
                Pair(single1result, single2result)
            }
    ).toFlowable()
            .flatMap { single1AndSingle2 ->
                if (isFirstLoad) {
                    createItemOrNull(single1AndSingle2.first, single1AndSingle2.second)?.let { result ->
                        Single.just(listOf(result)).mergeWith(proceedWithFinalNetworkCalls(single1AndSingle2))
                    }.orElse {
                        proceedWithFinalNetworkCalls(single1AndSingle2).toFlowable()
                    }
                } else {
                    proceedWithFinalNetworkCalls(single1AndSingle2).toFlowable()
                }
            }.doOnComplete {
                isFirstLoad = false
            }

fun proceedWithFinalNetworkCalls(): Flowable<List> {
          return Single.zip(
                            single3(single1result),
                            single4(single2result),
                            single5(single1result),
                            single6(single2result),
                            Function4 { single3Result: Object,
                                        single4Result: Object,
                                        single5Result: Object,
                                        single6Result: Object ->
                                ObjectHolder(single1Result, single2Result, single3Result, single4Result, single5Result, single6Result)
                            }
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, it's in Java but from what I've understood, something like that may be a possible solution?

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final Single<String> single1 = single1().cache();

    single1.map(List::of)
           .mergeWith(single1.zipWith(single2(), Map::entry)
                             .flatMap(entry -> Single.zip(
                                                      single3(entry.getKey()),
                                                      single4(entry.getValue()),
                                                      single5(entry.getKey()),
                                                      single6(entry.getValue()),
                                                      (el3, el4, el5, el6) -> objectHolder(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue(), el3, el4, el5, el6))))
           .subscribe(System.out::println,
                      System.err::println);

    Flowable.timer(1, MINUTES)  // Just to block the main thread for a while
            .blockingSubscribe();
}

private static List<String> objectHolder(final String el1,
                                         final String el2,
                                         final String el3,
                                         final String el4,
                                         final String el5,
                                         final String el6) {
    return List.of(el1, el2, el3, el4, el5, el6);
}

static Single<String> single1() {
    return Single.just("s1");
}

static Single<String> single2() {
    return Single.just("s2");
}

static Single<String> single3(String value) {
    return single("s3", value);
}

static Single<String> single4(String value) {
    return single("s4", value);
}

static Single<String> single5(String value) {
    return single("s5", value);
}

static Single<String> single6(String value) {
    return single("s6", value);
}

static Single<String> single(String value1, String value2) {
    return Single.just(value1).map(l -> l + "_" + value2);
}
```

This outputs:

```
[s1]
[s1, s2, s3_s1, s4_s2, s5_s1, s6_s2]
```

Comment: Hey, so I'm having trouble making this work, but thats probably because my example wasn't accurate enough, my apologies.  After getting 1 and 2 I need to do a conditional, and then emit results if it's true.  With your example, I imagine I would need to return the results or an empty list so it would complete probably, but I'm struggling to make this work with the merge and mapping now.  I can't keep access to 1 and 2 results and then merge.   I updated my actual question to reflect the mistake I made when posting it.

Comment: Okay, I finally I got it working using the merge idea you showed. I kept the initial BiFunction but instead of doing all the stuff in there, I just returned a Pair(single1result, single2Result).  I then turn that whole zipped single into a flowable, flatmap the pair out, and then do my if statements.  I then either merge the final zip into the result when I need to return it, or I just return the zip without the merge in the else condition.  I'll post the tweaked solution in my post and you can update/modify and then I can accept your answer.  I wouldn't have gotten this without your help.

Comment: Great to know, it was helpful!